# Intel UP Squared AI Vision Dev Kit - Factory Reset

Tags: system-installation, intel

I am working on a Intel UP Squared AI Vision Dev Kit and need to clean the entire system back to factory settings. How do I do that?

The problem is the Ubuntu installation that comes with the kit is customized for the product. So, I want to go back to this not a simple clean Ubuntu version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just refreshed my UP2 AI edge kit and re-installed OpenVino R2.

Not sure what comes in vision kit but i got back most of the applications installed on it earlier.

Also reach out to UP2 team to see if they can provide you with their base image.